# Can Android stop a service while app is in foreground?

Tags: android, android-service

In my app there is a service started in the first activity's onCreate and I would like to make sure that the service is running as long as the app remains in foreground.

Is it possible that the system stops the service while the app is in the foreground?

Comment: A service runs on the same thread as the ui, so I don't see a reason to do that.

Comment: Question: Has the OS ever terminated your service? I doubt it would, as long as the app is in foreground.

Comment: i was looking for something similar, i will link you my code tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the system is going to unilaterally destroy your `Service` in this circumstance. That is, I've never seen it do that (but I don't have any references to back that up).

If you had said, "...and the Service is bound to the Activity", I would go even further: "The Service is not going to be destroyed while it is bound," because that would imply sudden calls to `onServiceDisconnected()`, not prompted by an `unbindService()`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation that is a possibility sometimes:

> A service process is one holding a Service that has been started with the startService() method. Though these processes are not directly visible to the user, they are generally doing things that the user cares about (such as background network data upload or download), **so the system will always keep such processes running unless there is not enough memory to retain all foreground and visible processes.**
>   **Services that have been running for a long time (such as 30 minutes or more) may be demoted in importance to allow their process to drop to the cached LRU list described next.** This helps avoid situations where very long running services with memory leaks or other problems consume so much RAM that they prevent the system from making effective use of cached processes.

([source](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle))

Comment: But in my case this process is not a "service process" but a "foreground process" since the app is in foreground, right ? (I assume that the app and the service are running in the same process)

Comment: how are you starting your service? It could be just semantics, but a Service is held in service processes and those can be foreground or background.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice here is to use ForegroundService. It is a regular service which calls startForeground() method that ensures the service to be running. It is widely used for example by music players...so as you can figure, nobody likes when system kills music service in middle of a song playing. This should do.
 More in [Service Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know when to start and stop the service.

Create AppLifeCycleHandler `Class`

```
public class AppLifeCycleHandler implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks, ComponentCallbacks2 {

    private AppLifeCycleCallback appLifeCycleCallback;

    private boolean appInForeground;

    public AppLifeCycleHandler(AppLifeCycleCallback appLifeCycleCallback) {
        this.appLifeCycleCallback = appLifeCycleCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        if (!appInForeground) {
            appInForeground = true;
            appLifeCycleCallback.onAppForeground();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTrimMemory(int i) {
        if (i == ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) {
            appInForeground = false;
            appLifeCycleCallback.onAppBackground();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration configuration) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {

    }

    interface AppLifeCycleCallback {

        void onAppBackground();

        void onAppForeground();
    }
}
```

Now inside your `public class MyApplication extends Application`

Add the following code `implements AppLifeCycleHandler.AppLifeCycleCallback`

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        AppLifeCycleHandler appLifeCycleHandler = new AppLifeCycleHandler(this);
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(appLifeCycleHandler);
        registerComponentCallbacks(appLifeCycleHandler);
}
```

And finally :

```
    @Override
    public void onAppBackground() {
        Log.d("LifecycleEvent", "onAppBackground");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAppForeground() {
        Log.d("LifecycleEvent", "onAppForeground");
    }
```

Now last thing you need to do is to create the service,Follow this link 
[create-start-stop-android-background-service](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-create-start-stop-android-background-service/) 
And put your start intent and stop intent in the method we just created inside your application class